# Employer not responding to my calls after making an offer

Tags: professionalism, communication, hiring-process, job-offer

One and half month ago, I started to work on a mission of 1 month (ended on November 20). At the end of my mission, the employer gave me two options:

- work from home (I'm 250km away from the office) for an other two months.
- work at their office on an unlimited basis

The company is very busy right now, because it is very quickly growing. The boss is the only one in charge with recruiting people, and also has to manage the business growth.

Last Friday (28 November), I told I was ok for the first offer (work from home) directly to the boss. Since then, they told me they will send me the contract on Monday (1st of December),
but I never got it. 
I tried to call the boss at least a dozen times since Tuesday, and the two times he answered,
he told me that he was so busy that he couldn't write the contract. He told me both times he will call me back on that evening but never did.

I spoke with the person who was in charge of me for the 1 month I worked there,
and he seemed to be willing to have me on board, but didn't seem to be aware of the situation. Since the job offer is only for two months, I don't want to wait an other week to start the job, but would of course like to do that job.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boss acknowledges he made you an offer. Be happy with that.  Your calling "six times since Tuesday" may achieve nothing more than get your offer rescinded if he is annoyed enough with the frequency of your calling and he equates the frequency of your calling with nagging. People who are being tortured rarely show any gratitude or appreciation for having been tortured. And you are probably torturing him with your calls.

Try telling him that you have willing to start working remotely without a contract until he sends you one, hopefully within one to two weeks.

Or you can try telling him that you are willing to work at the office on a temporary basis to help ease the load until he comes through with the contract, hopefully within one to two weeks. If you are in the office every day and cranking away at your tasks and otherwise meaningfully contributing to the firm's growth, your presence will be a daily reminder to him that he needs to clean up his act and come up with the contract. Yeah, you live 250 klicks away but your eagerness to get started kind of tells me that you need the money - I was pretty good at dozing off on the train and waking up just before my stop in my time.